# Wordpress ACF delete image on library from field

Tags: wordpress, image, field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use update_value filter hook of Advanced Custom Fields to write a function that when a user deletes an image from the field it will be deleted from the media library of WP as well. So far i haven't managed to make it work i get lots of errors. I need to check if the value of the field is empty then get the previous value (the image) find the ID and delete the attachment? Any ideas?

```
//Delete image from acf field
function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field  )
{

    if (empty($value)){
    $var = get_field($field, $post_id);
    $varid = $var['id'];
    wp_delete_attachment( $var, true );
    }
    // do something else to the $post object via the $post_id
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/update_value/type=image', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

This are the errors I get:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/html/wp-includes/meta.php on line 484
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/html/wp-includes/meta.php on line 484
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/html/wp-includes/meta.php:484) in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/html/wp-admin/post.php on line 233
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/html/wp-includes/meta.php:484) in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi, it's been a while but no:)

Comment: Have you found a solution already? :)